# Counting number of states that a switchboard can be in

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider two separate switchboards $A$ and $B$  with $n_A = 4$ switches on switchboard $A$ and $n_B=16$ switches on switch board $B$. Each switch can be either on or off and this occurs with equal probability. I'm trying to find the probability that $3$ switches are up on switchboard $A$ given that there are a total of $12$ switches which are up on the combined system $A$ and $B$.

My attempt: Total number of states for the combined system which have 12 "on" switches is $20 \choose 12$. The number of states in system $A$ alone which have 3 on switches is $4 \choose 3$ and the number of states in system $B$ alone which have $9$ on switches is $16 \choose 9$, so the probability is given by the number of ways system $A$ can have 3 on and system $B$ can have 9 on, divided by the total $$\frac{{4\choose 3}   {16\choose 9}}{20 \choose 12} \approx 0.3633$$
does this look correct?

Comment: By your description of the problem, each switch is on or off *independently*